# How should I replace the PyQt4 function QRectF.unite() to work with PyQt5?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt

I am trying to convert a program originally coded in PyQt4 into PyQt5. However, in PyQt5, `QtCore.QRectF.unite()` is no longer supported. I've supplied my code here:

```
if cwidth != width or cheight != height:
    obj.width = width
    obj.height = height
    obj.updateObjCache()

    oldrect = obj.BoundingRect
    oldrect.translate(cx * 24, cy * 24)
    newrect = QtCore.QRectF(obj.x(), obj.y(), obj.width * 24, obj.height * 24)
*   updaterect = oldrect.unite(newrect)

    obj.UpdateRects()
    obj.scene().update(updaterect)
```

This code gets used if `obj`'s height or width has changed. Since I need to convert the line with the * to PyQt5, how should I replace `unite()` so that the code can run as it would in PyQt4?

Comment: Why didn't you just [look it up in the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qrectf.html#united)? It would have been a lot quicker than posting a question.

Comment: use the following link http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qrectf.html

Comment: Well, I actually realized that `united()` does the trick. I'm working in PyQt, by the way, it's very different from regular Qt.